# How to avoid ignite clients from continuously reconnecting to the cluster during startup

Tags: ignite, gridgain

When I use the Ignite standard client to connect to the Ignite server cluster, if the Ignite cluster has not been created yet, the "Ignition. start" method will never return until the Ignite server cluster is started.

Looking at the logs, it seems that the client has been trying to reconnect:

```
[10:51:15] Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry to join topology every 2000 ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries): [/127.0.0.1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47501]
```

How can I avoid this situation, which may block the startup of my application, or are there any settings regarding the threshold for reconnection times and timeout time?

Comment: You can offload thin client startup to separate thread